# Dict comprehension in python with random choices will lose elements sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create a dict in this way at first:

```
{x: [] for x in np.random.randint(100, size=10)}
```

Later, I found that the size of this dict will vary(sometimes 10, sometimes 9 and sometimes 8).
I thought it's the problem of the function randint. So I change it to:

```
{x: [] for x in [np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 101)) for x in range(10)]}
```

But the problem still exist.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The behaviour you see is because dictionaries can't have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random()` gives you same results sometimes, and they overwrite each other when you try to put them in `dict()` -- you have to make a decision to have really random numbers (with repetitions) and use `list()` or use `dict()` with no repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)
Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set.

```
print(sorted(list(random.sample(range(1, 101), 10))))
```